# How to call a parameter label of type closure (Swift)

Tags: swift, parameters, closures, function-call

Closures As Parameters

```
let driving = {
    print("I'm driving in my car.")
}

func travel(action: () -> Void) {
    print("I'm getting ready to go.")
    action()
    print("I arrived!")
}

travel(action: driving)
```

`action` is a parameter label. How come we consider it as a function call as in `action()`?

Comment: A closure is a function (to put it simply), and this parameter is of a closure type `() -> Void` - i.e. a function that takes no parameters and returns a `Void`. You can read more about closures [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at a brief example:

`func myFunction() {...}` Swift sees this as () -> Void

the same way that Swift sees this `"John"` as `String`

So when you write a function like `myFunction` you could really say

`func myFunction() -> Void {...}` for the same result.

Now action is defined as a parameter as a function but the type that it accepts for that parameter is `() -> Void` aka a closure which for now you can think of just another function.

So the line action() is just the *call* of that function.

But be sure to read up on [functions accepted as parameters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)